# Dual Entry Accounting + Bug in my code somewhere = :(

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, accounting

I was going to ask this in the Money Stack Exchange but I think because this is much more of a programming question it would be better here. I've already tried getting help from multiple non-programmer accountants and it was a disaster.

I have 3 models: `Account`, `JournalEntry`, `LineItem`

#### Account

- `category` corresponds with `%i[asset liability equity income expense]`
- `normal_balance` corresponds with `%i[debit credit]`
- Notice account with ID of `3` is a contra account (it's a `credit` account where asset accounts are usually `debit`)

[image: account]

#### JournalEntry

[image: journal entry]

#### LineItem

- `side` corresponds with `%i[debit credit]`
- `amount` is ALWAYS positive

[image: line item]

---

So I'm having some real difficulty with the 'contra' accounts.

I THINK I have a potential problem in my data model. I notice that many people in other accounting libraries store `amount` as +/- without storing `side`. I chose to store the `side` of the line item as well as `amount` as an always positive number to model real-world accounting on paper (remember I also store `normal_balance` of account so thats what I compare it to).

I understand this is slightly slower with math but I wanted to get it working first without making it overly confusing on myself.

The other reason I stored it like that is so it's more intuitive when adding new transactions. The accountant helping me agreed that saying `+200` or `-150` is confusing rather than saying `debit the sales account`. So I can write this:

```
Transaction.create!(:debit, sales, 200)
```

rather than

```
Transaction.create!(accumulated_depreciation, -140.30)
```

The problem is now I'm trying to write some formulas to do 2 actions:

1. A Balance category function which I will use 5 times to calculate the trial balance (i.e. I balance all categories individually and plug the results into the formula to get `0.00`: `asset balance` - (`liability balance` + `equity balance` + `income balance` - `expense balance`))
2. Balance a particular account (like for a P&L line like `Sales` account)

Here are my functions which do that. Notice how `balance_account` however doesn't involve taking `contra` into account.

```
def balance_category(category)
  # ...

  LineItem
    .joins(:account)
    .where('accounts.category = ?', category_index)
    .sum('CASE WHEN line_items.side = accounts.normal_balance THEN (CASE WHEN accounts.contra = false THEN line_items.amount ELSE -line_items.amount END) ELSE (CASE WHEN accounts.contra = false THEN -line_items.amount ELSE line_items.amount END) END')
end

def self.balance_account(account)
  # ...

  LineItem
    .joins(:account)
    .where('accounts.id = ?', account.id)
    .sum('CASE WHEN line_items.side = accounts.normal_balance THEN line_items.amount ELSE -line_items.amount END')
end
```

I tried getting the help of a non-programmer accountant to verify this but it was hopeless. I tried myself playing around with it but contra accounts are quite confusing and I question if this is correct, even though my trial balances work.

I'm making this post is because while programming 
 a P&L report I realized... if I do `balance_category` on `:asset`, I get one total. But if I do `balance_account` on all accounts IN that category, and then add those totals together, I **dont** get the same number if I have line items which are from a contra account. So something is wrong, somewhere.

My intuition says it might be with the fact that `balance_account` doesn't take contra into account, but I am not certain...

Comment: Did you consider using a gem like [`double_entry`](https://github.com/envato/double_entry)? Especially when it comes to database transactions and thread safety implementing something on your own gets tricky.

Comment: Yes, it won't work well for my particular needs. I have no problem with locks and transactions though, just this bit is kind of a brain warp

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was missing after a very long call with an accountant... when you store the value, you actually need to flip the sign AGAIN if it's a contra account.

Here's the function I use to store the proper sign on each amount (its called once per line item)

```
if side == normal_balance
  # do nothing
else
  amount = amount * BigDecimal(-1)
end

amount = amount * BigDecimal(-1) if account.contra?
```

I realize the logic can be simplified but I wanted to be explicit because its quite a mindwarp